# Nginx Rewrite to another path on the server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is it possible to do a rewrite rule in nginx to rewrite to another location on the server, outside of the current account?

For example, I want to rewrite `image123.jpg` to location on the server `/dev/shm/123.jpg`. Is this possible?

I could grab the image with a PHP script and rewrite to that, but I'd rather it was done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible: have a look at the [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)-directive